# How to drag and drop images with swift exactly?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I have an image on my screen that you can drag and drop. That works already. When I put my finger in the middle. 
Just as I put my finger in any corner (or anything else that is not the middle), the middle of the image gets under my finger. But I still want to have the corner.

Here is my code:

```
let frameDoor = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 400)
var doorView = ObjectView(frame: frameDoor)
doorView.image = UIImage(named: "door")
doorView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
doorView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(doorView)
```

ObjectView:

```
import UIKit

class ObjectView: UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var touch = touches.first
        self.center = (touch?.location(in: self.superview))!
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `self.center = (touch?.location(in: self.superview))!`.

You should calculate the offset from the center in `touchesBegan` and then add it when moving the image.

I cannot test the code right now, but it should give you an idea of how to do it.

```
var initialLocation: CGPoint?    
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     var touch = touches.first
     initialLocation = CGPoint(x: (touch?.location(in: self.superview))!.x - self.center.x, y: (touch?.location(in: self.superview))!.y - self.center.y)
}


override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    var touch = touches.first
    self.center = CGPoint(x: (touch?.location(in: self.superview)).x! - initialLocation.x, y: (touch?.location(in: self.superview)).y! - initialLocation.y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but now the image isn't under my finger anymore. Maybe I can fix it...

Comment: @chocolatecake, I've edited the answer. The calculation of the `initialLocation` is correct now. Don't forget to reset it when the touches are ended or cancelled.

Comment: Yes, now it works! I just fixed it by adding a secondary `initialLocation` that contains the initial location of the object. And I calculated the new position like this:
`let xPos = ((touch?.location(in: self.superview))?.x)! - initialLocationFinger!.x;
        let yPos = ((touch?.location(in: self.superview))?.y)! - initialLocationFinger!.y;
        self.center = CGPoint(x: initialLocationObject!.x + xPos, y: initialLocationObject!.y + yPos);`
But I think your solution is smarter ;)

Comment: @chocolatecake, they are both correct. Sorry for not giving the solution right away - I couldn't test the code. I would appreciate if you accept the answer. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: No problem! You helped me a lot! Thank you!